# using randint function for image encryption in matlab

Tags: matlab, encryption, random

I am working on a image encryption technique.For key generation purpose i used the function randint

```
key1=randint(256,256,[0,255]);
```

now I saved key1 as a png image for decryption purpose.But when I am reading it in the decryption stage,the content of key1 is changed drastically.most of the values are 255.why this is happening and what will be the possible solution??

It generates a warning also
"Warning: This is an obsolete function and may be removed in the future.
         Please use RANDI instead.
         To disable this warning, type warning('off','comm:obsolete:randint')"

Comment: How exactly do you save it as png? Concerning the warning: well, just follow it and use randi, it takes the same arguments, only in different order. FYI: randint doesn't exist in 2011b anymore - that's what I'm using here...

Comment: i used randi also.but still the key value is different in both encryption side and decryption side.i am saving the image as

    imwrite(key1,'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\KEY.png');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `randi` is double, and I think that is causing the issue.  From [Matlab help](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html):

> If A is a grayscale or RGB color image of data type double or single, then imwrite assumes the dynamic range is [0,1] and automatically scales the data by 255 before writing it to the file as 8-bit values.

In this case, the easiest way around it would be to cast key1 to uint8 with `key1 = uint8(key1);`